# Json Array into ListBox/Memo in Delphi xe7

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe7

I'm trying to catch the following JSON array :

```
[{"name":"Bryan","email":"Bryan@hotmail.com"},
 {"name":"Louis","email":"Louis@hotmail.com"},
 {"name":"Maria","email":"Maria@hotmail.com"},
 {"name":"Test","email":"test@hotmail.com"},
 {"name":"Anthony","email":"anthony@hotmail.com"}]
```

and put it in `Memo` or `ListBox` in Delphi :
the code is the following :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var jv: TJSONValue;
    jo: TJSONObject;
    jp: TJSONPair;
    ja: TJSONArray;
    i: integer;
    j: integer;
begin
    RESTRequest1.Execute;

    jv:=RESTResponse1.JSONValue;


    jo:= TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(jv.ToString) as TJSONObject;

    try
      for i := 0 to jo.Size - 1 do
      begin
        jp := jo.Get(i);
        if jp.JsonValue is TJSONArray then
        begin
            ja := jp.JsonValue as TJSONArray;
            for j := 0 to ja.Size -1 do
              Memo1.Lines.Add(ja.Get(i).ClassName + ': ' + ja.Get(j).ToString);
        end
        else
          Memo1.Lines.Add(jp.ClassName + ': '+ jp.ToString);

      end;
    finally
      jo.Free;
    end;
end;
```

When I click in Button  I got the following error message :

> **Invalid class typecast**

during debugging the following line has a problem :
`jo:= TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(jv.ToString) as TJSONObject;`

I don't know how to resolve this problem or this mistake , 
Could you please help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Clearly the value returned from `TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(jv.ToString)` is not derived from `TJSONObject`. Perhaps it is `nil`. You can debug this quite easily. If you wanted us to help you'd need to produce an MCVE. It would be very easy to do so. We don't have the REST. What we need is that value of `jv.ToString`. You could make a 10 line MCVE for this. Learning how to debug is really your goal here.

Comment: Well if you change your JSON it will work.  
`{"Persons": <The array as standing above>}` Works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer David. I suppose you are talking about the example but what do you mean by 10 lines of MCVE ? the value of jv.ToString is shown already is the Json array

Comment: do you think the json array need to be changed ?

Comment: So why are you confusing us with all the REST? For all we know the REST doesn't work.

Comment: David , there is no confusion here.the REST RESPONSE array was not correct and it was mentioned in the description of my question .

Comment: Well, I beg to differ. See my answer for an example of what I mean. The program in my answer strips away all the extraneous code and homes in on just the code that produces the error. I'm a believer that the particular issue you face is not the most important thing. The most important thing is to learn how to tackle such issues. You don't want to have to ask a question here everytime an `as` cast fails do you? I've tried to show you how to understand every such error of this form that you will ever encounter in the future. I think that's really the big picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem of `TJSONObject` is with the string you posted.
For some reason it will parse it if you changed it.

```
{"Persons":[{"name":"Bryan","email":"Bryan@hotmail.com"},{"name":"Louis","email":"Louis@hotmail.com"},{"name":"Maria","email":"Maria@hotmail.com"},{"name":"Test","email":"test@hotmail.com"},{"name":"Anthony","email":"anthony@hotmail.com"}]}
```

If I run the code as it is I get the following result
[image]

If you don't mind using something different than default Delphi units I would suggest superobject ([Link here](https://code.google.com/p/superobject/downloads/list))
superobject will parse your JSON edited and as posted.

Your code would look like this:

```
Const
  MyJSON = '[{"name":"Bryan","email":"Bryan@hotmail.com"},{"name":"Louis","email":"Louis@hotmail.com"},{"name":"Maria","email":"Maria@hotmail.com"},{"name":"Test","email":"test@hotmail.com"},{"name":"Anthony","email":"anthony@hotmail.com"}]';    
procedure ParseJSON;
  var
    obj: ISuperObject;
    Ar: TSuperArray;
    I: integer;
  begin
    obj := SO(MyJSON);
    if obj.IsType(stArray) then
    begin
      Ar := obj.AsArray;
      try
        for I := 0 to Ar.Length-1 do
          L.Add(Ar.O[I].AsString);
      finally
        Ar.Free;
      end;
    end
    else
      L.Add(Obj.AsString);
  end;
```

Result:
[image]

For Koul, to get the element names and values.
Like I said not very pretty code but ok.

```
Ar.O[0].AsObject.GetNames.AsArray.S[0]
```

To cut it up in pieces a bit.

```
Ar.O[0] //Get the first element in the array as ISuperObject  
.AsObject //Get it as TSuperTableString
.GetNames //Gets all names in the array, in this case "name" and "email"
.AsArray[0]//Get the first name in the names array.
```

It will result in `email` (Names are sorted A-Z)

You can do the same for the values by calling `GetValues` instead of `GetNames`.
I think the prettiest way to get it will be defining 2x more `TSuperArray`

```
procedure PrintNamesAndValues;
Var
  Ar, ArNames, ArValues:TSuperArray;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Ar := SO(<JSON string>).asArray;  
  ArNames := Ar.O[0].AsObject.GetNames.AsArray;
  ArValues := Ar.O[0].AsObject.GetValues.AsArray;
  For I := 0 to ArNames.Length-1 do
    WriteLn(Format('%s: %s',[ArNames.S[I], ArValues.S[I]]));  
end;
```

Hope it's all clear enough :)

Comment: This can be readily parsed with the built in JSON parser. The point is that the root of the JSON is an array rather than an object.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes I noticed it when I posted my answer. didn't see your answer by the time I started writing mine.  I worked with the built in JSON parser a bit but I like superobject better. Ofcourse it's a personal preference, it just feels easier and nicer to work with :)

Comment: The thing is, the asker would have the same problem with a different parser. Switching parser is a major change. Step 1 is to understand the JSON issues. The parser used is much less important to the problem at hand, and in my view obfuscates the prime issue.

Comment: Perhaps. Maybe it's a flaw in ISuperObject but when I parse the original JSON as posted I don't get an error on it.

Comment: Can we with ISuperObject get the JSON string and JSON value of each element of JSON array ?

Comment: @koul It's easy to do with the stock JSON parser. It saddens me that you'd rather change parser than actually understand what the problem was. JSON really is incredibly simple and knowing the difference between object and array is a prerequisite.

Comment: Thanks for you both for your clarification. as I m really a new in json/Delphi , this topic is very helpfull for anyone wants to understand how to tackle Json in Delphi . Thanks again

Comment: Just so that you are clear that the problem is not in the parser, but rather in your code.

Answer (score 1):

This could perfectly well be worked out by reading the code and looking at the JSON. However, I'd like to show you how to go about debugging such a problem in case you cannot work it out by static analysis. When an `as` cast fails that is always because the object on the left hand side of the `as` does not derive from the type on the right hand side. The next step then is always to inquire as to what the type of the object on the left hand side is. I've included a short MCVE above as a means to demonstrate.

The output of this program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.JSON;

const
  JSON = '[{"name":"Bryan","email":"Bryan@hotmail.com"},' +
         ' {"name":"Louis","email":"Louis@hotmail.com"},' +
         ' {"name":"Maria","email":"Maria@hotmail.com"},' +
         ' {"name":"Test","email":"test@hotmail.com"},' +
         ' {"name":"Anthony","email":"anthony@hotmail.com"}]';

begin
  Writeln(TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSON).ClassName);
end.
```

is

```
TJSONArray
```

Now, `TJSONArray` does not derive from `TJSONObject`. Hence your `as` cast raise a runtime error. If you cast the value returned by `ParseJSONValue` to `TJSONArray` that will succeed.

This is to be expected since the root of your JSON is an array and is not an object.

You need to modify your code so that it does not assume that the root level is always an object. You need different behaviour for arrays and objects.

Comment: The design of the library is partly to blame. It's perfectly understandable to expect a method called as `TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue` to return an instance of `TJSONObject`. I don't understand why that method doesn't belong to `TJSONValue` instead. The terminology can be confusing, too. All these classes yield instances that in Delphi terms we would call "JSON objects," but only some of them are what JSON calls objects. It's not immediately clear to novices which `TJSONObject` refers to (although it's not hard to figure out, either).

Comment: @Rob Yes, putting it in TJSONObject is very bizarre. Whilst I do think superobject is better, I don't see any need to change to solve this problem. And the asker would have been best served stepping back and understanding JSON terminology.